# Is it possible to mount an s3 bucket as a point in a docker container?

Tags: docker, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-s3, java

I have a Java EE packaged as war file stored in an `AWS s3` bucket. I will like to mount the folder containing the `.war` file as a point in my docker container. I have managed to do this on my local machine. Below is an example of a JBoss wildfly deployments. How can I use `s3` for this ?

`` docker container run -d —name Application -p 8080:8080 -v `pwd` /Application.war: /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/Application.war jboss/wildlfly ``

Comment: Worth checking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49379881/mount-s3fs-as-docker-volume (but really, you shouldn't do that in my opinion as it breaks the idea of repeatable self contained artifact of docker containers)

Comment: @Tensibai Agreed. Could you indicate why you do not bake the war inside the docker image? The docker image should be immutable.

Comment: @030 opposite, I would copy the war in the container at build time, not have a container relying on external source by taking the war at runtime as asked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't.

S3 is an object storage, accessed over HTTP or REST for example. Just as you can't mount an HTTP address as a directory you can't mount a S3 bucket as a directory.

Having said that there are some workarounds that expose S3 as a filesystem - e.g. 's3fs' project. How reliable and stable they are I don't know.

Comment: [it is possible indeed](https://blog.vizuri.com/practical-persistent-cloud-storage-for-docker-in-aws-using-rexray-pt-1)

[also for registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/storage-drivers/s3/)

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes , you can ( and in swarm mode you should )

- [rexray example](https://blog.vizuri.com/practical-persistent-cloud-storage-for-docker-in-aws-using-rexray-pt-1)
- [s3vol example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49379881/mount-s3fs-as-docker-volume)
- [in fact with volume plugins you may attach many things](https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/legacy_plugins/#volume-plugins)
- [also for registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/storage-drivers/s3/)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can use Fuse (eluded to by the answer above).

> S3FS-FUSE: This is a free, open-source FUSE plugin and an easy-to-use
>   utility which supports major Linux distributions & MacOS. S3FS also
>   takes care of caching files locally to improve performance. This
>   plugin simply shows the Amazon S3 bucket as a drive on your system.

https://tecadmin.net/mount-s3-bucket-centosrhel-ubuntu-using-s3fs/

I haven't used it in AWS yet, though I'll be trying it soon.  There is a similar solution for Azure blob storage and it worked well, so I'm optimistic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.
Use Storage Gateway service. It will give you a NFS endpoint. Mount that using kubernetes volumn.
It is possible. I have already achieved this.